# How to get value from Vec::pop()?

Tags: rust, vector

I see `pop()` method of vector returns an `Option` type. What the right way to get `pop()` value to a variable?

```rust
let mut queue: Vec<[usize; 2]> = Vec::new();
queue.push([1, 2]);
queue.push([3, 4]);

let coords = queue.pop();
println!("{}, {}", coords[0], coords[1]);
```

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `std::option::Option<[usize; 2]>`
  --> src/main.rs:99:24
   |
99 |     println!("{}, {}", coords[0], coords[1]);
   |
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know for a fact that `queue` will never be empty when you call `pop` on it, you can [unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) the option:

```
let coords = queue.pop().unwrap();
```

Otherwise, you can match on it and do whatever handling you need to in the `None` case:

```rust
let coords = match queue.pop() {
    Some(top) => top,
    None => {
        // … handling …
    }
};
```

Another possibility, useful if you only want to do something when the option is `Some`, is use [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html):

```
if let Some(coords) = queue.pop() {
    println!("{}, {}", coords[0], coords[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `.unwrap()` is good solution for my case. But now I have other problem, because `coords` variable have type `[usize, _]`, but I need `[usize, 2]`. I get `mismatched types` error. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @FelAA: Hm, I’d think it’d be `[usize; 2]`. Can you edit the error message into your question?

Comment: This is strange, but I can not reproduce this error after some changes :) I think it was wrong error message of IDE, because actually I had error with `usize` and `u8` mismatching. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a reason behind why `queue.pop()` would return an Option type?

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamer: It can’t remove and return a value from the queue if the queue is empty.